# Setup a network using 2 modem and 2 accesspoint

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, tomato

Our dormitory has been equipped with 2 ADSL lines for about 60 students. Most of us just used internet for chatting, web-surfing and email, but there are few guys want to suck all the network bandwidth with their IDM and uTorrent. Due to the poor setup of the networks, the internet become mostly useless.

Now I want to re-setup the network using current hardware (2 modem, 2 router, 1 PC with Windows 2003 installed on - for balance-loading).
I'm have very basic knowledge in networking, but I think I will upgrade all router to Tomato firmware for simple management interface, better speed and QoS control. I will set a limit so that no guys can download at a speed greater than 1/5 the overall bandwidth of the whole network (currently it's 2 Mbps)

With these conditions, how do I setup the network so that our students would have some small happiness?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Windows Server 2003 doesn't have any ability to load-balance two Internet connections. Even ISA Server can't do that.

Comment: People say that Windows Server 2003 can provide network-balancing, doesn't it include Internet? Or it's just LAN?

Comment: It does include load IP load balancing for the server(s) itself, not for routing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're a way off being able to configure this properly - far easier to deal with this as a layer-8 problem and tell the culprits go grip up and play nice.

Comment: +1, i would confront the offenders first. Plus, 2Mbps is not a lot for 60 people.

Comment: So, you said limiting speed/client wont' help?

Comment: It will help yes, but it's probably MUCH easier to speak the people who are causing the problem than trying to use technology to fix it.